# Question regarding C++ Templates

Tags: c++, templates

I used a simple class for a test program about templates, this is what I did:

```
template <typename T>
class test
{
public:
    test<T>::test();
    T out();
};

template <typename T>
test<T>::test()
{
}

T test<T>::out()
{
}

int main()
{
    //test<int> t;
}
```

But when I try to compile it says **'T' : undeclared identifier** and **use of class template requires template argument list** , pointing to the same line, where I have implemented the method **out()** . Can anyone please explain what the problem is?? I'm using visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 5):

Following is more accurate:

```
template <typename T>
class test
{
public:
    test();
    T out();
};

template <typename T>
test<T>::test()
{
}

template <typename T>
T test<T>::out()
{
}
```

1) Don't use `<T>` inside class
2) Don't forget to declare template  `<T>` before each method declaration out of class body

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the out member is missing the template argument list. out should read:-

```
template <typename T>
T test<T>::out() 
{ 
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't indent the code, so the `<typename T>` was taken as an unknown HTML element and ignored.

Comment: Whoops - good point, although I think the answer is still right - I just got the wrong missing argument list.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
test<T>::test();
```

Just write this:

```
test();
```

Comment: This is wrong; that would just define a new free function instead of the class method.

Comment: I guess I should have been clearer. I'm referring to the declaration in the class, not the definition after. (The semicolon should give it away.)

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. -(-1) :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is related to the scoping of the template class and the definition of its member functions. When defining member functions outside the class template, you need to specify the template parameter (T) in the scope of the class. just remove the unnecessary test:: qualifiers from the member function declarations inside the class.The constructor and out() method definitions outside the class include the template parameter  within the scope of the class template.